# Complex Polygon Area

Tags: java, arrays, area

cloneList =   Point[] (series of points put into constructor)
I have tried so many different times to fix this formula, but am coming up wanting. The formula was found on
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula
index(i) is a point which has both x and y values.

```
public double getArea() {
    double area = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < cloneList.length-1; i++){



    area += cloneList[i].getX()*cloneList[i+1].getY() - cloneList[i+1].getX()+cloneList[i].getY();

}


    area = area/2;
    //System.out.println(Math.abs(area));
return Math.abs(area);
}
```

Comment: What do you add to the variable area when i = cloneList.length-1?  Hint: it isn't the right thing to add at this point.

Comment: Um... I have no idea..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with this formula but ill give it a shot...
To me it looks as though you are not following the formula correctly, this would be my implementation(based on what i gleaned from the wiki page xD)

```
public double getArea(){
    double area = 0;
    int n = cloneList.length;
    double firstSum = 0;
    double secondSum = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i< cloneList.length - 1;i++){
        firstSum+= cloneList[i].getX()*cloneList[i+1].getY();
        secondSum+= cloneList[i+1].getX()*cloneList[i].getY();
    }
    firstSum+=cloneList[cloneList.length-1].getX()*cloneList[0].getY();
    secondSum-=cloneList[0].getX()*cloneList[cloneList.length-1].getY();

    double finalSum = firstSum-secondSum;
    area = Math.abs(finalSum)/2;
    return area;



}
```